Trying to install dpkg manually: subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status
I'm buiding my own Linux OS and I need dpkg installed so I can install .deb packages.
To do so, I have made a script that can download .deb and manually extract these and insert them into the file system.
The following code is a script for downloading dpkg 1.22 for my CPU. In this case, it's armhf.
# Download dpkg from ubuntu
wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.22.0ubuntu1_armhf.deb

# Extract it
ar -x dpkg_1.22.0ubuntu1_armhf.deb
unzstd data.tar.zst 
tar -xvf data.tar

# Copy
cp -a ./usr /
cp -a ./etc /
cp -a ./var /
cp -a ./sbin /
cp -a ./lib /

# Clean
rm -r *

# Download
wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/libm/libmd/libmd0_1.1.0-2build1_armhf.deb

# Extract it
ar -x libmd0_1.1.0-2build1_armhf.deb
unzstd data.tar.zst 
tar -xvf data.tar

# Copy
cp -a ./usr /

# Clean
rm -r *

# Download
wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/x/xz-utils/liblzma5_5.6.2-2_armhf.deb

# Extract it
ar -x liblzma5_5.6.2-2_armhf.deb
unzstd data.tar.zst 
tar -xvf data.tar

# Copy
cp -a ./usr /

# Clean
rm -r *

# Download
wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.38-1ubuntu6.3_armhf.deb

# Extract it
ar -x libc6_2.38-1ubuntu6.3_armhf.deb
unzstd data.tar.zst 
tar -xvf data.tar

# Copy
cp -a ./usr /
cp -a ./etc /
cp -a ./lib /

# Clean
rm -r *

# Download
wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/b/bzip2/libbz2-1.0_1.0.8-6_armhf.deb

# Extract it
ar -x libbz2-1.0_1.0.8-6_armhf.deb
unzstd data.tar.zst 
tar -xvf data.tar

# Copy
cp -a ./usr /

# Clean
rm -r *

# Download
wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/libs/libselinux/libselinux1_3.5-2ubuntu5_armhf.deb

# Extract it
ar -x libselinux1_3.5-2ubuntu5_armhf.deb
unzstd data.tar.zst 
tar -xvf data.tar

# Copy
cp -a ./usr /

# Clean
rm -r *

# Download
wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/p/pcre2/libpcre2-8-0_10.42-4ubuntu2_armhf.deb

# Extract it
ar -x libpcre2-8-0_10.42-4ubuntu2_armhf.deb
unzstd data.tar.zst 
tar -xvf data.tar

# Copy
cp -a ./usr /

# Clean
rm -r *

# Download
wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/libz/libzstd/libzstd1_1.5.5+dfsg2-2build1.1_armhf.deb

# Extract it
ar -x libzstd1_1.5.5+dfsg2-2build1.1_armhf.deb
unzstd data.tar.zst 
tar -xvf data.tar

# Copy
cp -a ./usr /

# Clean
rm -r *

# Download
wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/z/zlib/zlib1g_1.3.dfsg-3.1ubuntu2.1_armhf.deb

# Extract it
ar -x zlib1g_1.3.dfsg-3.1ubuntu2.1_armhf.deb
unzstd data.tar.zst 
tar -xvf data.tar

# Copy
cp -a ./usr /

# Clean
rm -r *

# Download
wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/t/tar/tar_1.35+dfsg-3build1_armhf.deb

# Extract it
ar -x tar_1.35+dfsg-3build1_armhf.deb
unzstd data.tar.zst 
tar -xvf data.tar

# Copy
cp -a ./usr /
cp -a ./etc /

# Clean
rm -r *

# Download
wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/z/zlib/zlib1g_1.3.dfsg-3.1ubuntu2.1_armhf.deb

# Extract it
ar -x zlib1g_1.3.dfsg-3.1ubuntu2.1_armhf.deb
unzstd data.tar.zst 
tar -xvf data.tar

# Copy
cp -a ./usr /

# Clean
rm -r *

# Download
wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/a/acl/libacl1_2.3.2-2_armhf.deb

# Extract it
ar -x libacl1_2.3.2-2_armhf.deb
unzstd data.tar.zst 
tar -xvf data.tar

# Copy
cp -a ./usr /

# Clean
rm -r *

## Configure dpkg

# Download
wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/g/glibc/libc-bin_2.38-1ubuntu6.3_armhf.deb

# Extract it
ar -x libc-bin_2.38-1ubuntu6.3_armhf.deb
unzstd data.tar.zst 
tar -xvf data.tar

# Copy
cp -a ./usr /
cp -a ./sbin /
#cp -a ./var / <- Don't need because it's empty
cp -a ./etc /

# Clean
rm -r *

And it's working (I cannot copy the text from Putty)


Problem:
When I'm going to install a .deb package, e.g apt, then it looks like this.

Question:
I'm guessing that I'm missing some files that are needed.
I have followed https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/dpkg and download all the packages that depends on dpkg. But still, I get this error.
Can some one understand why this error occurs?

Ubuntu 23.10 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/07/17/ubuntu-23-10-mantic-minotaur-reached-end-of-life-on-july-11-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades   Your don't specifically mention any release, but package versions in pastes are all for 23.10 or mantic; check your logic as much detail you provided isn't 24.04 but 23.10 thus EOL & why packages aren't there

Presumably dpkg expects to find GNU tar but is finding busybox tar

@steeldriver yes, it must be that case! I will change the path of BusyBox Tar to GNU Tar, if it's not the same already.

@steeldriver Yes, it was! I changed /bin/tar to /bin/tar2 and now i'm using /usr/bin/tar. It's working.
